# Verificar si un form está dentro de un listado en un array

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo el siguiente código JavaScript.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var f_ur = $("form#ultimos_registros");
    var f_m = $("form#movimientos");
    var f_c = $("form#conductores");
    var f_v = $("form#vehiculos");
    var f_a = $("form#asignaciones");
    var arr_forms = [];
    arr_forms.push(f_ur);
    arr_forms.push(f_m);
    arr_forms.push(f_c);
    arr_forms.push(f_v);
    arr_forms.push(f_a);
    $("form").on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        for (var i = 0; i < arr_forms.length; i++) {
            if (arr_forms[i] == $(this)) {
                console.log("Se hizo submit a un form dentro del array");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Lo que intento hacer es recolectar **forms** específicos de la página web en un `Array()`. Entonces, cuando un form entre en submit, quiero que compruebe si este mismo está o no en el array().

No me funciona. ¿Cuál es entonces la solución?

Comment: ¿No te conviene asignarles una clase y generar el evento sólo para los forms de esa clase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es mejor que guardes de los formularios que quieres únicamente el identificador, no todos los parámetros del formulario. Al darle click en cualquiera de los formularios de la página, entrará en el evento, recorrerás tu array compárando el ID del formulario al que le dieron el submit, con los ID's de los formularios de tu Array:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var f_ur = $("form#ultimos_registros").attr('id');
  var f_m = $("form#movimientos").attr('id');
  var f_c = $("form#conductores").attr('id');
  var f_v = $("form#vehiculos").attr('id');
  var f_a = $("form#asignaciones").attr('id');
  var arr_forms = [];
  arr_forms.push(f_ur,f_m,f_c,f_v,f_a);
  $("form").on('submit', function(event) {    
      event.preventDefault();
      for (var i = 0; i < arr_forms.length; i++) {
          if (arr_forms[i] == $(this)[0].id) {
              console.log("Se hizo submit a un form dentro del array");
          }
      }
  }); 
});
```

Hice un [snippet en Codepen](http://codepen.io/akh000/full/LRaEkK/) para tests

Answer (score 1):

Porque lo tienes que recolectar?

Creo que es más simple si detectas quien de las `<form>`'s se ha enviado.

Lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```js
$(function() {    
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Se ha enviado la form con la id: '+$(this)[0].id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form_1">
    <input type="submit" value="form_1">
</form>
<br>
<form id="form_2">
    <input type="submit" value="form_2">
</form>
<br>
<form id="form_3">
    <input type="submit" value="form_3">
</form>
```

Comment: Interesante respuesta

Comment: `$(this)[0].id ` puede escribirse de forma menos verbosa directamente como `this.id`

Comment: Esto es solo una demostración... podría haber puesto cualquier cosa... Es mejor dejarlo así porque si quiere seguir trabajando con `jQuery` no vale `this` sin el selector de jQuery... [ver ejemplo](http://jsbin.com/muqohoyori/2/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Lo que me quería referir es : para qué crear un elemento jQuery `$(this)`, si luego obtienes el elemento DOM "original" : `$(this)[0]` ? . Si quieres trabajar con jQuery `$(this).attr('id')`, con puro JS `this.id`. Pero veo una transformación innecesaria `$(this)[0]`. Funciona igual de bien tú código, pero innecesario es.

Comment: Pero si lo tienes claro que es solo una demostración no?